# When using the Fetch API, why do post requests require more inputs than a get request?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

How come when we use the Fetch API, it requires a significant amount of more input into the function for a `POST` request as opposed to a `GET` request. This has been a bit of a learning curve for myself. Also, what determines the headers you need to use for a `POST` request?

Comment: What do you mean by "*significant amount of more input*", can you show some examples?

Comment: Well, the main distinction between GET and POST requests in HTTP is that the former *doesn't have input* (a request body) whereas the latter does (while both do have output, i.e. the response body). So it isn't unexpected that a POST `fetch()` call requires inputs…

Comment: "*what determines the headers you need to use for a POST request?*" - the API of the server. HTTP itself [requires very few headers](https://serverfault.com/q/163511/492195) (and those are set automatically if you use the `fetch` function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR, `POST` has more stuff to it.

`GET` and `POST` are methods for [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods). The main ones of interest are:

- `GET`: get a thing
- `POST`: make a new thing
- `PUT`: change a thing
- `DELETE`: delete a thing

The most basic form of a `GET` is asking a specific URI to send back pre-set data. Also, `GET` tends to be the most common use request so most HTTP request-making methods will make this very simple. Thus, `GET` is often done with little more than a URI.

In contrast, `POST` has a lot going on.

1. You aren't making a `GET` request. This is more specific to Fetch API as it assumes `GET` by default so you need to specify in the options that you are using `method: "POST"`.
2. You are, by definition, sending data. Therefore, you must include that data in the method: `body: myData`
3. Data has a format. The server has no idea if you sent it a string, and integer, a JSON, or the whole Harry Potter movie set. It just sees a stream of 1s and 0s. This is where headers come in, which let you specify to the server that you are sending it a JSON object or an image file so that the server can appropriately deal with the bits. Thus, we see [`headers: { 'Content-Type': <MIME type of myData> }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) in the options.